# mysql system user

Tags: mysql

Quoting from the MySQL docs here

> If this is system user, it refers to a nonclient thread spawned by the server to handle tasks internally. This could be the I/O or SQL thread used on replication slaves or a delayed-row handler. unauthenticated user refers to a thread that has become associated with a client connection but for which authentication of the client user has not yet been done. event_scheduler refers to the thread that monitors scheduled events. For system user, there is no host specified in the Host column.

What is a MySQL system user?
How can I create a system user for MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't *create* the 'system user'. This is a special user that MySQL uses for purposes like those described in the docs. Specifically: Processes that do not primarily originate from user interaction. Since these use MySQL threads and resources, they also appear in `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

Comment: They appear in `SHOW PROCESSLIST` only for users who have permission to see other user's jobs.

Comment: "Show Full Processlist" shows empty host for a user 'm'. MySQL Doc says, For system user, there is no host specified in the Host column.

Comment: That's strange... This [old bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22723) mentions such a behaviour if a MySQL 5.0 server has been started with `--skip-grant`, but I'm sure your server isn't that old. Other than that, I have no idea.